# Place an image on top of another

Tags: php, gd

Is there a way to place an image on the top of an other to produce one image?

Comment: Not an answer as such but there seems to have been a discussion and solution here: http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/how-do-i-merge-various-images-into-one-using-gd-502604.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`imagecopy()`](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.imagecopy.php) can do that

Comment: I think he meant to 'merge/combine' the images, not to position them over each other.

Comment: GD is a php library for manipulating images. I think the topic of the question is about merging images

Comment: -1. Images do have something to do with PHP. Note that he tagged the qustion 'gd', meaning he wants to use the gd library to manipulate images in his PHP code... Perhaps he wants to add a watermark or something? Its a legitimate question, and it can be done.

Comment: you almost scared me with the first question

Answer (score 0):

If you can get away with overlaying the images in your HTML, then just use CSS to position two `<img>` tags on top of each other; the transparent (or semi-transparent) areas of the one on top will let the one behind show through. Easy.

However, if you actually want to output a single merged image (as your use of the 'gd' tag suggests), yes it can be done. You will need to write some code, of course!

Here is a link to pages which discusses how to do it. (there's quite a bit of discussion there, so it's easier to link to it than try to summarise it myself)

- http://codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=72317